# How to make a slider full width in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the below slider have a full width. If someone could help me, I'd appreciate it greatly.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SlidesJS Standard Code Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SlidesJS is a simple slideshow plugin for jQuery. Packed with a useful set of features to help novice and advanced developers alike create elegant and user-friendly slideshows.">
  <meta name="author" content="Nathan Searles">

  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS for slidesjs.com example -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- End CSS for slidesjs.com example -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Optional: If you'd like to use this design -->
  <style>
    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font: normal 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #232525;
      padding-top:70px;
    }

    #slides {
      display: none
    }

    #slides .slidesjs-navigation {
      margin-top:5px;
    }

    a.slidesjs-next,
    a.slidesjs-previous,
    a.slidesjs-play,
    a.slidesjs-stop {
      background-image: url(img/btns-next-prev.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      display:block;
      width:12px;
      height:18px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      float: left;
      margin-right:5px;
    }

    a.slidesjs-next {
      margin-right:10px;
      background-position: -12px 0;
    }

    a:hover.slidesjs-next {
      background-position: -12px -18px;
    }

    a.slidesjs-previous {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }

    a:hover.slidesjs-previous {
      background-position: 0 -18px;
    }

    a.slidesjs-play {
      width:15px;
      background-position: -25px 0;
    }

    a:hover.slidesjs-play {
      background-position: -25px -18px;
    }

    a.slidesjs-stop {
      width:18px;
      background-position: -41px 0;
    }

    a:hover.slidesjs-stop {
      background-position: -41px -18px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination {
      margin: 7px 0 0;
      float: right;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 1px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a {
      display: block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 0;
      padding-top: 13px;
      background-image: url(img/pagination.png);
      background-position: 0 0;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
      background-position: 0 -13px
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
      background-position: 0 -26px
    }

    #slides a:link,
    #slides a:visited {
      color: #333
    }

    #slides a:hover,
    #slides a:active {
      color: #9e2020
    }

    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Optional-->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: These styles are required if you'd like a responsive slideshow -->
  <style>
    #slides {
      display: none
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    /* For tablets & smart phones */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      body {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
      }
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smartphones */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smaller displays like laptops */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
      .container {
        width: 724px
      }
    }

    /* For larger displays */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container {
        width: 1170px
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: -->
</head>
<body>

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->
  <!-- The container is used to define the width of the slideshow -->
  <div class="container">
    <div id="slides">
      <img src="img/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="Photo by: Missy S Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/listenmissy/5087404401/">
      <img src="img/example-slide-2.jpg" alt="Photo by: Daniel Parks Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/parksdh/5227623068/">
      <img src="img/example-slide-3.jpg" alt="Photo by: Mike Ranweiler Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/27874907@N04/4833059991/">
      <img src="img/example-slide-4.jpg" alt="Photo by: Stuart SeegerLink: http://www.flickr.com/photos/stuseeger/97577796/">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
  <script>

    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        play: {
          active: true,
          auto: true,
          interval: 4000,
          swap: true
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
  SlidesJS 3.0.4 http://slidesjs.com
  (c) 2013 by Nathan Searles http://nathansearles.com
  Updated: June 26th, 2013
  Apache License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*/
(function(){(function(e,t,n){var r,i,s;s="slidesjs";i={width:940,height:528,start:1,navigation:{active:!0,effect:"slide"},pagination:{active:!0,effect:"slide"},play:{active:!1,effect:"slide",interval:5e3,auto:!1,swap:!0,pauseOnHover:!1,restartDelay:2500},effect:{slide:{speed:500},fade:{speed:300,crossfade:!0}},callback:{loaded:function(){},start:function(){},complete:function(){}}};r=function(){function t(t,n){this.element=t;this.options=e.extend(!0,{},i,n);this._defaults=i;this._name=s;this.init()}return t}();r.prototype.init=function(){var n,r,i,s,o,u,a=this;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);e.data(this,"animating",!1);e.data(this,"total",n.children().not(".slidesjs-navigation",n).length);e.data(this,"current",this.options.start-1);e.data(this,"vendorPrefix",this._getVendorPrefix());if(typeof TouchEvent!="undefined"){e.data(this,"touch",!0);this.options.effect.slide.speed=this.options.effect.slide.speed/2}n.css({overflow:"hidden"});n.slidesContainer=n.children().not(".slidesjs-navigation",n).wrapAll("<div class='slidesjs-container'>",n).parent().css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"});e(".slidesjs-container",n).wrapInner("<div class='slidesjs-control'>",n).children();e(".slidesjs-control",n).css({position:"relative",left:0});e(".slidesjs-control",n).children().addClass("slidesjs-slide").css({position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,width:"100%",zIndex:0,display:"none",webkitBackfaceVisibility:"hidden"});e.each(e(".slidesjs-control",n).children(),function(t){var n;n=e(this);return n.attr("slidesjs-index",t)});if(this.data.touch){e(".slidesjs-control",n).on("touchstart",function(e){return a._touchstart(e)});e(".slidesjs-control",n).on("touchmove",function(e){return a._touchmove(e)});e(".slidesjs-control",n).on("touchend",function(e){return a._touchend(e)})}n.fadeIn(0);this.update();this.data.touch&&this._setuptouch();e(".slidesjs-control",n).children(":eq("+this.data.current+")").eq(0).fadeIn(0,function(){return e(this).css({zIndex:10})});if(this.options.navigation.active){o=e("<a>",{"class":"slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation",href:"#",title:"Previous",text:"Previous"}).appendTo(n);r=e("<a>",{"class":"slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation",href:"#",title:"Next",text:"Next"}).appendTo(n)}e(".slidesjs-next",n).click(function(e){e.preventDefault();a.stop(!0);return a.next(a.options.navigation.effect)});e(".slidesjs-previous",n).click(function(e){e.preventDefault();a.stop(!0);return a.previous(a.options.navigation.effect)});if(this.options.play.active){s=e("<a>",{"class":"slidesjs-play slidesjs-navigation",href:"#",title:"Play",text:"Play"}).appendTo(n);u=e("<a>",{"class":"slidesjs-stop slidesjs-navigation",href:"#",title:"Stop",text:"Stop"}).appendTo(n);s.click(function(e){e.preventDefault();return a.play(!0)});u.click(function(e){e.preventDefault();return a.stop(!0)});this.options.play.swap&&u.css({display:"none"})}if(this.options.pagination.active){i=e("<ul>",{"class":"slidesjs-pagination"}).appendTo(n);e.each(new Array(this.data.total),function(t){var n,r;n=e("<li>",{"class":"slidesjs-pagination-item"}).appendTo(i);r=e("<a>",{href:"#","data-slidesjs-item":t,html:t+1}).appendTo(n);return r.click(function(t){t.preventDefault();a.stop(!0);return a.goto(e(t.currentTarget).attr("data-slidesjs-item")*1+1)})})}e(t).bind("resize",function(){return a.update()});this._setActive();this.options.play.auto&&this.play();return this.options.callback.loaded(this.options.start)};r.prototype._setActive=function(t){var n,r;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);r=t>-1?t:this.data.current;e(".active",n).removeClass("active");return e(".slidesjs-pagination li:eq("+r+") a",n).addClass("active")};r.prototype.update=function(){var t,n,r;t=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);e(".slidesjs-control",t).children(":not(:eq("+this.data.current+"))").css({display:"none",left:0,zIndex:0});r=t.width();n=this.options.height/this.options.width*r;this.options.width=r;this.options.height=n;return e(".slidesjs-control, .slidesjs-container",t).css({width:r,height:n})};r.prototype.next=function(t){var n;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);e.data(this,"direction","next");t===void 0&&(t=this.options.navigation.effect);return t==="fade"?this._fade():this._slide()};r.prototype.previous=function(t){var n;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);e.data(this,"direction","previous");t===void 0&&(t=this.options.navigation.effect);return t==="fade"?this._fade():this._slide()};r.prototype.goto=function(t){var n,r;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);r===void 0&&(r=this.options.pagination.effect);t>this.data.total?t=this.data.total:t<1&&(t=1);if(typeof t=="number")return r==="fade"?this._fade(t):this._slide(t);if(typeof t=="string"){if(t==="first")return r==="fade"?this._fade(0):this._slide(0);if(t==="last")return r==="fade"?this._fade(this.data.total):this._slide(this.data.total)}};r.prototype._setuptouch=function(){var t,n,r,i;t=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);i=e(".slidesjs-control",t);n=this.data.current+1;r=this.data.current-1;r<0&&(r=this.data.total-1);n>this.data.total-1&&(n=0);i.children(":eq("+n+")").css({display:"block",left:this.options.width});return i.children(":eq("+r+")").css({display:"block",left:-this.options.width})};r.prototype._touchstart=function(t){var n,r;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);r=t.originalEvent.touches[0];this._setuptouch();e.data(this,"touchtimer",Number(new Date));e.data(this,"touchstartx",r.pageX);e.data(this,"touchstarty",r.pageY);return t.stopPropagation()};r.prototype._touchend=function(t){var n,r,i,s,o,u,a,f=this;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);u=t.originalEvent.touches[0];s=e(".slidesjs-control",n);if(s.position().left>this.options.width*.5||s.position().left>this.options.width*.1&&Number(new Date)-this.data.touchtimer<250){e.data(this,"direction","previous");this._slide()}else if(s.position().left<-(this.options.width*.5)||s.position().left<-(this.options.width*.1)&&Number(new Date)-this.data.touchtimer<250){e.data(this,"direction","next");this._slide()}else{i=this.data.vendorPrefix;a=i+"Transform";r=i+"TransitionDuration";o=i+"TransitionTimingFunction";s[0].style[a]="translateX(0px)";s[0].style[r]=this.options.effect.slide.speed*.85+"ms"}s.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd",function(){i=f.data.vendorPrefix;a=i+"Transform";r=i+"TransitionDuration";o=i+"TransitionTimingFunction";s[0].style[a]="";s[0].style[r]="";return s[0].style[o]=""});return t.stopPropagation()};r.prototype._touchmove=function(t){var n,r,i,s,o;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);s=t.originalEvent.touches[0];r=this.data.vendorPrefix;i=e(".slidesjs-control",n);o=r+"Transform";e.data(this,"scrolling",Math.abs(s.pageX-this.data.touchstartx)<Math.abs(s.pageY-this.data.touchstarty));if(!this.data.animating&&!this.data.scrolling){t.preventDefault();this._setuptouch();i[0].style[o]="translateX("+(s.pageX-this.data.touchstartx)+"px)"}return t.stopPropagation()};r.prototype.play=function(t){var n,r,i,s=this;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);if(!this.data.playInterval){if(t){r=this.data.current;this.data.direction="next";this.options.play.effect==="fade"?this._fade():this._slide()}e.data(this,"playInterval",setInterval(function(){r=s.data.current;s.data.direction="next";return s.options.play.effect==="fade"?s._fade():s._slide()},this.options.play.interval));i=e(".slidesjs-container",n);if(this.options.play.pauseOnHover){i.unbind();i.bind("mouseenter",function(){return s.stop()});i.bind("mouseleave",function(){return s.options.play.restartDelay?e.data(s,"restartDelay",setTimeout(function(){return s.play(!0)},s.options.play.restartDelay)):s.play()})}e.data(this,"playing",!0);e(".slidesjs-play",n).addClass("slidesjs-playing");if(this.options.play.swap){e(".slidesjs-play",n).hide();return e(".slidesjs-stop",n).show()}}};r.prototype.stop=function(t){var n;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);clearInterval(this.data.playInterval);this.options.play.pauseOnHover&&t&&e(".slidesjs-container",n).unbind();e.data(this,"playInterval",null);e.data(this,"playing",!1);e(".slidesjs-play",n).removeClass("slidesjs-playing");if(this.options.play.swap){e(".slidesjs-stop",n).hide();return e(".slidesjs-play",n).show()}};r.prototype._slide=function(t){var n,r,i,s,o,u,a,f,l,c,h=this;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);if(!this.data.animating&&t!==this.data.current+1){e.data(this,"animating",!0);r=this.data.current;if(t>-1){t-=1;c=t>r?1:-1;i=t>r?-this.options.width:this.options.width;o=t}else{c=this.data.direction==="next"?1:-1;i=this.data.direction==="next"?-this.options.width:this.options.width;o=r+c}o===-1&&(o=this.data.total-1);o===this.data.total&&(o=0);this._setActive(o);a=e(".slidesjs-control",n);t>-1&&a.children(":not(:eq("+r+"))").css({display:"none",left:0,zIndex:0});a.children(":eq("+o+")").css({display:"block",left:c*this.options.width,zIndex:10});this.options.callback.start(r+1);if(this.data.vendorPrefix){u=this.data.vendorPrefix;l=u+"Transform";s=u+"TransitionDuration";f=u+"TransitionTimingFunction";a[0].style[l]="translateX("+i+"px)";a[0].style[s]=this.options.effect.slide.speed+"ms";return a.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd",function(){a[0].style[l]="";a[0].style[s]="";a.children(":eq("+o+")").css({left:0});a.children(":eq("+r+")").css({display:"none",left:0,zIndex:0});e.data(h,"current",o);e.data(h,"animating",!1);a.unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd");a.children(":not(:eq("+o+"))").css({display:"none",left:0,zIndex:0});h.data.touch&&h._setuptouch();return h.options.callback.complete(o+1)})}return a.stop().animate({left:i},this.options.effect.slide.speed,function(){a.css({left:0});a.children(":eq("+o+")").css({left:0});return a.children(":eq("+r+")").css({display:"none",left:0,zIndex:0},e.data(h,"current",o),e.data(h,"animating",!1),h.options.callback.complete(o+1))})}};r.prototype._fade=function(t){var n,r,i,s,o,u=this;n=e(this.element);this.data=e.data(this);if(!this.data.animating&&t!==this.data.current+1){e.data(this,"animating",!0);r=this.data.current;if(t){t-=1;o=t>r?1:-1;i=t}else{o=this.data.direction==="next"?1:-1;i=r+o}i===-1&&(i=this.data.total-1);i===this.data.total&&(i=0);this._setActive(i);s=e(".slidesjs-control",n);s.children(":eq("+i+")").css({display:"none",left:0,zIndex:10});this.options.callback.start(r+1);if(this.options.effect.fade.crossfade){s.children(":eq("+this.data.current+")").stop().fadeOut(this.options.effect.fade.speed);return s.children(":eq("+i+")").stop().fadeIn(this.options.effect.fade.speed,function(){s.children(":eq("+i+")").css({zIndex:0});e.data(u,"animating",!1);e.data(u,"current",i);return u.options.callback.complete(i+1)})}return s.children(":eq("+r+")").stop().fadeOut(this.options.effect.fade.speed,function(){s.children(":eq("+i+")").stop().fadeIn(u.options.effect.fade.speed,function(){return s.children(":eq("+i+")").css({zIndex:10})});e.data(u,"animating",!1);e.data(u,"current",i);return u.options.callback.complete(i+1)})}};r.prototype._getVendorPrefix=function(){var e,t,r,i,s;e=n.body||n.documentElement;r=e.style;i="transition";s=["Moz","Webkit","Khtml","O","ms"];i=i.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+i.substr(1);t=0;while(t<s.length){if(typeof r[s[t]+i]=="string")return s[t];t++}return!1};return e.fn[s]=function(t){return this.each(function(){if(!e.data(this,"plugin_"+s))return e.data(this,"plugin_"+s,new r(this,t))})}})(jQuery,window,document)}).call(this);
```

I've included a direct demo to the above code: http://masluz.panamerik.net/playing/index.html

Comment: have you tried in javascript to change the i={width:940,height:528 dimensions by using 100%?
Can you jsffidlize this and reformulate your question please?

Comment: change it here: `.slidesjs({width: 940,` not in the SlideJS source

Comment: I've included a direct demo to the above code: http://masluz.panamerik.net/playing/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.container {
width: 100%;
}
```

BUT you will need images that are either full width sized or css to stretch it

edit..

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* For smartphones */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* For smaller displays like laptops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* For larger displays */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

you can use

```
.container img { width:100% }
```

to stretch the image.. but its best to find real images that has the amount of width needed..

add these to change image width.. to stretch

```
div#slides img {
max-height: 480px;
}
div#slides { height: 480px; }
```

Comment: Where does this code go? What does it do? What about the image height? (I know the answers, but the OP may not)

Comment: Vico i have changed the code for 100% width in the code but without changes :S

Comment: it just makes the containing box into a full width. the image size did not change so all you will see is it shifting to the left if you did not set the image size

Comment: Ok now i have changed to full width but now i need know how make 472px in height ;P